# Mismatched types on matching string

Tags: rust

I seem to be mixing types but I can't quite figure out how to fix this. Can someone help me?

```
let args_vector: Vec<String>  = env::args().collect();
for arg in &args_vector[1..]{
    match arg{
        "--bytes"  => {
                flag.c = true;
            },
        "--chars" => {
                flag.m =true;
            },
        _ => println! ("Error"),
    }
}
```

On the matches, I'm getting this error:

```
mismatched types: expected struct `std::string::String`, found str
```

Comment: Not related, but you can write `for arg in std::env::args().skip(1) { /*etc.*/ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here arg is of type `String` in the match and `"--bytes"` is of type `&str`. So `arg` of type `String` has to be converted to `&str`.  This can be done using `String::as_ref()`.

```
let args_vector: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
for arg in &args_vector[1..] {
    match arg.as_ref() {
        "--bytes" => {
            flag.c = true;
        }
        "--chars" => {
            flag.m = true;
        }
        _ => println!("Error")
    };
}
```

Note the missing `;` after `println!` to make all `match` arms return the same type.